# Spring Integration Conditional SpEL using Properties

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-el, spring-properties

Is there a way to use spring properties in a ternary expression on the `expression` field of a Spring `header-enricher`? Something that looks like this:

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="DESTINATION" expression="headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? ${route1.db} : ${route2.db}"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

This resulted to an error saying `Unexpected token. Expected 'colon(:)' but was 'lcurly({)'`. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="DESTINATION" expression="headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? '${route1.db}' : '${route2.db}'"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

or

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="DESTINATION" expression="#{headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? '${route1.db}' : '${route2.db}'}"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hassen! The first suggestion helped me realize that the property `route1.db` did not exist. Though this is just part of the fix, I'll accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of `Unexpected token. Expected 'colon(:)' but was 'lcurly({)'` was that there was no property `route1.db` existing in the properties file, and therefore the expression was evaluated as `headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? ${route1.db} : some-alternative-db`, leaving `${route1.db}` unchanged. This results to syntax error.

Additionally, @Hassen suggested to put single quotes which is needed to render the values from property files as proper strings. Without it, the evaluated expression `headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? direct-db : some-alternative-db` will treat both `direct-db` and `some-alternative-db` as Spring fields/properties which are even incorrectly named variables to start with.

The final, valid form should be:

```html
<int:header name="DESTINATION" expression="headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? '${route1.db}' : '${route2.db}'"/>
```

and given that the properties file contain the following:

`route1.db=direct-db
 route2.db=some-alternative-db`

the evaluated expression will be:

`headers['DATA'].routingKey == 'ROUTE1' ? 'direct-db' : 'some-alternative-db'`